# How to search by attributes and vendor address in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, function, woocommerce, attributes

I'm working on a code to have a search list of the product attributes automatically taken from the product attributes I had set up before.
But as a result I got a droplist full of empty fields.

And, in a second search field, I would like to have the possibility for searching the store location (ex. query=Boston), getting it from the store address ID in WC Vendors (I thought about #wcfmmp-store).
But this resulted as nothing.

Search by product attributes:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url( '/' ); ?>" class="search2">
 <input type="hidden" name="s" value=""/>
 <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product"/>
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/box_holder.png">

 <div class="search_box">
 <h3 class="search_title">Search by attribute</h3>
 <select class="selectBox" name="pa_color">
 [get_filter_options]( 'Color', 'pa_color' ); [/get_filter_options]
 </select> 
 <button class="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Its Function:

```
function get_filter_options( $title, $taxonomy ) {

global $wp_query;

$options = '' . $title . '';
$data = get_terms( $taxonomy );

foreach ( $data as $term ) {

$selected = isset( $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy] ) && $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy] == $term->term_id ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
$options .= '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '"' . $selected . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
  }
 return $options;
}

    /*SHORTCODE*/

 function sm_setup( $atts ) {
        add_shortcode( 'get_filter_options', 'get_filter_options' );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'sm_setup' );
```

Problem 2 - Vendors search by address:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="http://www.test.org/store/">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="wcfmmp-store">Search:</label>
<input type="search" id="wcfmmp-store" name="wcfmmp-store" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="">
<button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
    </form>
```

I really appreciate your opinion, thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that the method get_filter_options is return a list of options and they are all blank or it is not returning a list of options at all.

Comment: Yes, it returns a list of blank options.

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($data); exit; ?

Comment: Do you mean put it like this? If so, nothing happened. `}
    return $options;
var_dump($data); exit;
}   `

Comment: Pushing the search button I've got also a wrong url .../<?post_type=product&pa_color=